# Two versions of Hibernate when use Spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management

I clearly specified a recent Hibernate version in my build.gradle file. I found out two different version of Hibernate jar files showed up in my dependencies library list after ran a build. Spring boot introduced a lower version even I want to use 5.4.2.Final. Should I use the version that Spring boot introduced or is there a way to override it with a newer version?

I did some research but I didn't find an answer that I am looking for.

Comment: Did you update hibernate.version property ?

Comment: Your question have a point. I had multiple projects under a parents and I didn't specify hibernate in the one of children project. So, the hibernate version was implicitly taken from Spring boot. Of course the main issue was resolved by the answer listed bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Excluding transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:excluding_transitive_module_dependencies) : you can exclude `hibernate` libraries from Springboot transitive dependencies, in order to force Gradle to use your version.
First you need to analyse which Springboot dependency is dependent on `hibernate-core` (generally this is `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"`) : for this purpose you can use gradle `dependencies` task to browse the dependency graph.

Then you can exclude a specific transitive dependency as described in the documentation:

```
dependencies{

    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude group: "org.hibernate", module: "hibernate-core"
    }
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final"
    ...
}
```

Beware that upgrading `hibernate-core` version might have side effects on behavior of the Spring Jpa-related libraries (make sure that Springboot version you are using is compatible with this new version of `hibernate`)

EDIT : there are other ways available to define transitive dependencies contraints, please refer to the official documentation (e.g.: [Customizing Dependency Resolution Behavior](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:dependency_resolve_rules))